# Grails - multiple objects database relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship, grails-domain-class

I have a non-Grails specific question, but I intend to implement it with it.
Anyway. I would like to have a One-to-Many domain class relationship, but I would like the Many part to be of several different types.

For instance: 
A domain `Class Man` would have several `Friends` (this is our 1 to Many relationship), but the Friends bit could be another `Man` with its particular sets of methods and attribute, or a `Dog`, or a `Monster`, etc.

I have browsed the web but do not know how to name properly what i am searching for.
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: "but the Friends bit could be another Man with its particular sets of methods and attribute, or a Dog, or a Monster, etc." can you explain it more please ?

Comment: Hi,
I would like to create a 1 t Many relationship, but would like the Many part not to be of one fixed type. I would like to be able to assign several types possible to the objects stored on the Many side of the relationship. 
In my example above, a Man would have a field Friend, and a Friend could be of type Monster, Pet or Man for example.  
Any guess of how to implement this, and which technologies it involves ?

Comment: Ok I have been affected to some other stuff in the meantime, but I go back to you when I'll implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I am not sure %100 but you should do something like this. You need an interface for inheritance.

```
interface Alive{
        //just definition
     }

class Friend implements Alive {

//definition
}

class Pet implements Alive{
//definition
}

Person{
 static hasMany = [ alives: Alive]
}
```

Comment: Looks good at least :)
Thank you. I know one of the restrictions of inheritance in GORM is that you cannot allow 'nullable' fields. I'll check on it, try to implement it and go back to you to give you a feedback on how it went. 

Thanks again !

Comment: You can have nullable fields in the inheritance I think. You would need to use table-per-subclass instead of the default table-per-hierarchy setting. Specify static mapping = {     tablePerHierarchy false }. See section 5.5.2.3 for more: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping